# No access permission error with npm global install on docker image

Tags: docker, npm

I'm trying to build a **docker image with a global install** of firebase-tools and angular-cli.
I'm building the same image for two versions of node: 6.x (LTS boron) and v8.x (latest alpine). Locally, both images build fine, but when I try to build in docker hub only the v6.x builds successfully. With the v8.x it gets trapped in the **access permissions for undefined and nobody user**. I'm already using the root user (USER root), since without this setting (or using USER node) both images fail to build.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

USER root

RUN npm install --quiet --no-progress -g @angular/cli@latest firebase-tools
RUN npm cache clean --force
```

And this is the output:

```
Step 4/5 : RUN npm install --quiet --no-progress -g @angular/cli@latest firebase-tools

 ---> Running in fce3da11b04e

 npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
 /usr/local/bin/firebase -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/bin/firebase
 /usr/local/bin/ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> node-sass@4.5.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
  at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:890:18)
  at sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
  at Function.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
  at checkAndDownloadBinary (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:111:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:154:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)

errno: -13,
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'mkdir',
path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

> grpc@1.3.8 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.3.8/node-v57-linux-x64.tar.gz node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.3.8 and node@8.1.2 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp WARN EACCES user "undefined" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/8.1.2" gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN EACCES user "nobody" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp/8.1.2" gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN EACCES user "nobody" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp/8.1.2" gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN EACCES user "nobody" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp/8.1.2" gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN EACCES user "nobody" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp/8.1.2" gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp"
(infinite loop)
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The problem is because while NPM runs globally installed module scripts as the `nobody` user, which kinds of makes sense, recent versions of NPM started setting the file permissions for node modules to `root`. As a result module scripts are no longer allowed to create files and directories in their module.

See discussion [in NPM issue #3849](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3849), for some references.

A simple workaround, which makes sense in a docker environment, is to set the NPM default global user back to `root`, like so:

```
npm -g config set user root
```

After which you shouldn't have any more `EACCES` errors.

Comment: or also using  ```npm -g config set user $USER``` worked for me as I really want my user to be the default, not root.

Comment: @DanieleDellafiore setting the global user to the personal user ID doesn't make a lot of sense. Maybe you'd simply want to use npm without the global (`-g`) flag

Comment: trying to install `cordova-res`  globally wat not working, after this install success. thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Please **DO NOT** set the user to `root` or use `--unsafe-perm`.

Simply use the `node` user, provided with the current official (e.g. `alpine`) images.

Commented `Dockerfile` below:

```sh
FROM node:15.5-alpine

#  Security: do not use the `root` user.
ENV USER=node

# You can not use `${USER}` here, but reference `/home/node`.
ENV PATH="/home/node/.npm-global/bin:${PATH}"
#  The `--global` install dir
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX="/home/node/.npm-global"

# All subsequent commands are run as the `node` user.
USER "${USER}"

# Pre-create the target dir for global install.
RUN mkdir -p "${NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX}/lib"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

#  Configure NPM, so pkg get installed with correct credentials.
# Avoids `chmod u+x $DIR` and other workarounds.
RUN npm --global config set user "${USER}" \
    && npm --global --quiet --no-progress install \
    && npm cache clean --force
```

*Extended version of @gabriel-araujo answer.*

You can replace [setting the user](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#user) via the CLI flags (`npm --global config set user "${USER}"`) by configuring this [in the `.npmrc` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/npmrc). Place `user=node` in the project roots `.npmrc` file or just set it directly from the `Dockerfile`.

```sh
RUN echo "user=node" > "${NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX}/etc/.npmrc"
```

If you use `docker-compose.yml`, you can add it as `environment: - …` variable.

Hope that helps you running a more safe NodeJS container somewhere and pull up some awesome stuff.

Comment: This solution worked and I can install libs globally. But the problem that I'm now facing is that I'can expose a port. (with EXPOSE command or --expose run parameter). The container starts but closes immediately and don't give me any error message. Do you know how to expose a port with this configuration?

Comment: @dchang Have you tried running it with `-d`/ detached? Also: Have you tried running it with `run --rm` or `exec -it` and just opening a `sh`ell or `bash`? If this runs and the container persists, you can inspect the running containers logs by doing a `docker ps -a` to find the container and then `docker logs -f` to attach to the log output. That might help you while debugging.

Comment: I don't know what changed, but now I can expose a port successfully with this configuration. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get it working by **changing the default npm-global directory**.

This is my dockerfile now:

```
FROM node:latest
USER node

RUN mkdir /home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global

RUN npm install --quiet --no-progress -g @angular/cli@latest firebase-tools
RUN npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer. The accepted answer currently recommends to use `root` and gets much too many upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `--unsafe-perm` flag:

```
npm install --quiet --no-progress --unsafe-perm -g @angular/cli@latest firebase-tools
```

I think that's still better than setting the `npm` user permanently to root. You can use `--unsafe-perm` only with the packages which cause problem

Answer (score 0):

instead of forcing NPM's hand to install the package inside the container I bypassed this issue by mapping/referncing a host folder for the missing module
this also prevents future headaches for when I replace the docker image with the latest version,  I won't have to repeat the stages to reinstall the missing module inside the container:

the steps i took:

1. create an empty folder on the host environment (will be used as a target for the node js modules). call it **node_modules**
2. when launching running the docker container use the --volume and --env switches

-- volume to pass map the new host folder  (from step 1) to a folder accessible inside docker

--env to define/set an environment variable **NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX** from inside the docker to the  **/node_modules** folder we created in step 1

3. access the container using :

   sudo docker exec -i -t  sh

and go to the folder above the folder right above the **local** /node_modules folder (this not the folder we mapped to the environment variable, but rather the preexisting folder that came with the docker image)

then run the command:

```
> npm install -g <mdule-name>
```

example

```
> npm install -g request
```

this will install the module in the host folder we've created. this module will also be accessible from both docker and host.

Comment: @kaiser thanks, as long as people can still see and use the info... that's what's important