# I want to install mechanic on npm, I tried to run this line sudo npm install -g mechanic, but it gives me error, I don't understand this error

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx, npm

I want to install mechanic on my nginx server.

I got this error when I execute `sudo npm install -g mechanic`:

```
tigaron@galaxybrainpower:/var/www/tigaron$ sudo npm install -g mechanic
/usr/bin/mechanic -> /usr/lib/node_modules/mechanic/bin/mechanic

> fs-ext@2.0.0 install /usr/lib/node_modules/mechanic/node_modules/fs-ext
> node-gyp configure build

gyp WARN EACCES current user ("nobody") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/home/tigaron/.cache/node-gyp/10.20.1"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/mechanic/node_modules/fs-ext/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/mechanic/node_modules/fs-ext/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/mechanic/node_modules/fs-ext
gyp ERR! node -v v10.20.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fs-ext@2.0.0 install: `node-gyp configure build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fs-ext@2.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tigaron/.npm/_logs/2020-05-24T06_29_26_857Z-debug.log
```

What is happening here? How to fix this error and proceed with the installation?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45505787/10850779) solved the same issue I had when installing a different package.

Apparently the `nobody` user is used when building packages globally, but the directories are owned by `root` so it fails permissions. Configuring `npm` to use `root` with the following command is what the answer recommends.

```
npm -g config set user root
```