# Slow performance for `meteor build` when building docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, meteor

I'm trying to dockerize my meteor app and I'm finding `meteor build` to be extremely slow. When I run the command on my mac it completes in a couple minutes however when I run the command through docker, it takes well over 15 minutes.

Here's the dockerfile I'm using:

```
FROM node:12

# make sure we set up non root permissions for everything - make a workdirectory with permissions for user `node`
# and make all future commands run as user `node`
WORKDIR tripvector
RUN chown node:node ./
USER node

# needed so that we can install meteor as a non root user further below
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/44633420/1489726
RUN mkdir /home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global

RUN npm install -g meteor

# install the version of meteor required for this package. We use meteor --help because there isn't a more canonical way
# of downloading the required version of meteor
# meteor isn't available on the path without reloading the shell which we haven't figured out yet
COPY .meteor .
RUN ~/.meteor/meteor --help

COPY package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./

# For some reason meteor isn't in the path immediately after installing
RUN ~/.meteor/meteor npm install


COPY --chown=node . .

# need to change permissions of the .meteor folder so that we can build as a non-root user
# this is needed because `meteor build` needs to create a folder called `local` under the `.meteor` folder
USER root
RUN chown -R node:node .meteor
USER node

RUN ~/.meteor/meteor build --server-only --directory build && cd build/bundle/programs/server && ~/.meteor/meteor npm install

CMD ["sleep", "100000"]
```

The final `RUN` command in the dockerfile takes very long. It's currently been running for 1800 seconds which seems unusually slow to me considering how quickly it runs outside of docker:

```
 ❮❮❮ docker build . -t tripvector
[+] Building 1986.5s (15/16)
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12                                                                                                                                             1.6s
 => [ 1/12] FROM docker.io/library/node:12@sha256:e88281f7b3947019c8b5fe750a06122ac3c2612fe00719a133ea5bf8bfedafbb                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                      0.3s
 => => transferring context: 1.84MB                                                                                                                                                                    0.3s
 => CACHED [ 2/12] WORKDIR tripvector                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/12] RUN chown node:node ./                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/12] RUN mkdir /home/node/.npm-global                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/12] RUN npm install -g meteor                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/12] COPY .meteor .                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/12] RUN ~/.meteor/meteor --help                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [ 8/12] COPY package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./                                                                                                                                              0.2s
 => [ 9/12] RUN ~/.meteor/meteor npm install                                                                                                                                                         175.2s
 => [10/12] COPY --chown=node . .                                                                                                                                                                      0.6s
 => [11/12] RUN chown -R node:node .meteor                                                                                                                                                             0.9s
 => [12/12] RUN ~/.meteor/meteor build --server-only --directory build && cd build/bundle/programs/server && ~/.meteor/meteor npm install                                                           1807.4s
 => => # Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
 => => # npx browserslist@latest --update-db
 => => # Why you should do it regularly:
 => => # https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
 => => # Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
 => => # npx browserslist@latest --update-db
```

How can I get meteor to build my app more quickly for a docker image?

Comment: I use Meteor up, which does all the docker stuff for me with little fuss, and runs pretty quickly. It's open source, so you could have a look at how it does things to help you trouble-shoot

Comment: ah great idea, thanks for the tip, I'll take a look!